# Is phone using only GPS to get it's location?

Tags: android, gps

I am conducting test where we are compering GPS position of Android phone and GPS device which we would like to integrate in our hardware. But for the test to be accurate, phone need to use only GPS and not cell towers and WiFi.

Here is the code, where I set which service does the phone use.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager
            .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_MILLISECONDS_BEFORE_UPDATE_LOCATION,
                    MIN_METERS_BEFORE_UPDATE_LOCATION,
                    new MyLocationListener(this));
```

So will phone use only GPS to get it's location? I can' turn WIFI off, because phones are sending current locations to our data base. Both GPS device and phone are on a fixed location at the time of test.

I know that there are already questions how to use GPS for acquiring location, but I would like to make sure, that phone is using just GPS.

Comment: I know it's answered, but if you want to see for yourself, on your `MyLocationListener` you receive an instance of `Location` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()). You can call on this `location.getProvider()` to see who provided that location, you should be getting only `GPS` or some string similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can find location by only using GPS (Assuming that location is reachable, for example not underground or something like that) By using internet it just finds location faster. Since your device is stationary you should be ok.

Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Comment: I also track number of connected satellites and check if it's connected. Ok, so then internet and cellular network doesn't effect accuracy?

Comment: No, it does not affect accuracy.